# Discrete Fourier Transform algorithm not working properly?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform, discrete-calculus

I'm making a program where a vectorial image (set of complex points) is converted into a sum of complex waves.
I'm first doing the DFT of this set of points (the number may vary, usually it's around 100 to 1000) calculating the coefficients:
$$c_n=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=0}^{N - 1}{f(t)e^{-2\pi n i\frac{t}{N}}}$$
I calculate $101$ coefficients ($-50\leq n\leq50$).

Now that I have the coefficients I try to redraw the original shape, by doing the inverse DFT. I get a 2D curve but most of the times it gets just chaotic and diverges.
The formula I use to do this is:
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{N_C}c_ne^{2\pi nti}$$

Where $N_C$ is the number of coefficients used.
I tested my algorithms by using simple functions like the following as input instead of images:
$$f(t)=0.5e^{2\pi t i}+e^{3\cdot2\pi t i}$$
And I get $c_1=0.5$ and $c_3=1$ as expected, while every other coefficient is just $0$.
If i use this function as an input:
$$f(t)=e^{0.5\cdot2\pi t i}$$
I get strange results:
The coefficients between $-25$ and $25$ are:

| Re | Im |
| --- | --- |
| 0.003816815838070725 | 0.012315218857076468 |
| 0.003813591027954187 | 0.012862565533832103 |
| 0.003810100370944189 | 0.01345614355367736 |
| 0.0038063083980105065 | 0.014102273703532226 |
| 0.0038021730430501544 | 0.014808483672193947 |
| 0.003797644033982658 | 0.015583810793825061 |
| 0.0037926607888532186 | 0.016439200799321756 |
| 0.003787149629662038 | 0.017388040107298792 |
| 0.003781020041042592 | 0.01844687696126995 |
| 0.0037741595686217886 | 0.019636414570122863 |
| 0.0037664267427997542 | 0.020982904114953127 |
| 0.0037576410748355353 | 0.022520139212974098 |
| 0.0037475686073907646 | 0.024292378770455193 |
| 0.0037359005304209957 | 0.02635874571475219 |
| 0.003722220642032876 | 0.02880005281548732 |
| 0.0037059542190082478 | 0.03172978029462135 |
| 0.0036862846016637754 | 0.0353124932746145 |
| 0.00366201091096426 | 0.0397963546618827 |
| 0.003631291968961577 | 0.045574226113904465 |
| 0.0035911539091093743 | 0.05330793171742221 |
| 0.0035364608248771904 | 0.06420851151140089 |
| 0.0034575135452857234 | 0.08076509107412773 |
| 0.003333534321451747 | 0.1090896628519892 |
| 0.0031105269675283423 | 0.16979990844168213 |
| 0.0025906927272201746 | 0.42547968993915825 |
| 1.951997591342902E-15 | -2.2279944896489305E-16 |
| 0.007812325836175332 | -0.41937986251549136 |
| 0.0051945065938289285 | -0.1698637389622447 |
| 0.004672502264143089 | -0.10914343193900801 |
| 0.004448897029335363 | -0.08081604884385901 |
| 0.00432467176415203 | -0.06425826521749266 |
| 0.004245599938926926 | -0.053357054912080565 |
| 0.004190835222609711 | -0.04562297679486064 |
| 0.004150652220332767 | -0.0398448665762224 |
| 0.004119903242738353 | -0.03536084283873617 |
| 0.0040956084918419115 | -0.031778014396121726 |
| 0.004075923539739443 | -0.028848201842546873 |
| 0.0040596456055803 | -0.026406830236898944 |
| 0.004045956856629951 | -0.024340413212598392 |
| 0.0040342818142545854 | -0.022568133992855396 |
| 0.004024203772274635 | -0.021030866945578087 |
| 0.004015413573581822 | -0.019684351284790513 |
| 0.0040076770156440445 | -0.018494792053751236 |
| 0.0040008134325139055 | -0.01743593709573443 |
| 0.003994681223942561 | -0.016487082477533156 |
| 0.003989167837524223 | -0.015631679408706252 |
| 0.003984182683170614 | -0.014856341051377994 |
| 0.00397965202512267 | -0.014150121348875616 |
| 0.0039755152362089315 | -0.013503982710787482 |
| 0.003971722008543331 | -0.01291039724451122 |
| 0.003968230247372277 | -0.012363043999386375 |

Whose resulting curve is seems to be right on the X coordinate but it is just wrong on the Y.
The same exact thing happens with the vectorial image as an input.

Can you help me figure out what's the problem when there's an arbitrary set of points as an input?

Comment: Are you sure about your summation limits? It should be from $0$ to $N-1$, not $N$

Comment: @user3733558 yeah, right! I forgot it writing the question but my algorithm is correct.

Comment: Ok, I had to make sure. Now, I don't understand what $N_C$ represents, but if you want to recover the original curve by the inverse DFT, you need to use all coefficients, which means, you must have $N_C = N-1$ too.

Comment: @user3733558 still nothing. The imaginary part of the coefficients seems to be too small relative to the real part, and the curve resulting from the inverse is just like flat on the Y axis... So I suppose there's something wrong in the calculation of the coefficients.

Comment: well, other than that, I only noticed that it's unusual to normalize with $1/N$ when calculating the DFT coefficients, it's usually done in the inverse DFT calculations. Either that or making the transforms unitary by multiplying by $1/\sqrt{N}$ in both directions.

Comment: Well, I did that because the formula for the coefficient was
 $$c_n=\sum_{t=0}^{N - 1}{e^{-2\pi n i\frac{t}{N}}\Delta t}$$
And I just assumed that $\Delta t$ is $\frac{1}{N}$.
Am I right? Or I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123283/discussion-between-frank-soll-and-user3733558).

Comment: Should your second formula be $$f(t)=\sum_{n=-50}^{50}c_ne^{2\pi nti/N}$$ (I changed the start and end values for $n$ and added a $1/N$ scale factor in the exponent.)

Comment: More importantly, you're referring to "images" and "shapes", which implies two dimensions, but you're computing a 1-dimensional Fourier transform? Can you provide more detail about how $f(t)$ relates to these images/shapes?

Comment: f(t) returns the t-th point as a complex value. x coordinate is associated to the real part, while y coordinate is associated to the imaginary part.

Comment: @Bungo why should the exponent be scaled by $1/N$?

Comment: @FrankSoll Check the definitions for DFT and inverse DFT. The exponents differ only by a minus sign.

Comment: @Bungo oh, right. Thanks, I'm going to see if works.

Comment: Btw, one more thing that might be affecting you, or maybe it's just a typo: "I calculate $100$ coefficients ($-50\leq n\leq50$)." If those really are both $\leq$ then that's a range of $101$ indices, not $100$.

Comment: @Bungo edited. Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, and I feel a bit stupid about it... I was doing multiplication locally so when the algorithm was running the coefficients were constantly changing. Another problem was the missed $1/N$ in the exponent for the inverse transform as @Bungo suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a set of $N$ points $\{x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{N-1}\}$ then the DFT is
$$\hat{x}_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_ne^{-2\pi i \frac{nk}{N}}$$
Now it is key to understand what are the DFT coefficients and what is their range.

If $N$ is odd, the first $(N-1)/2$ terms are $\{\hat{x}_{-\frac{N-1}{2}},\hat{x}_{-\frac{N-1}{2}+1},\hat{x}_{-\frac{N-1}{2}+2},...,\hat{x}_{-2},\hat{x}_{-1}\}$, then the next term is $\hat{x}_0$ and the subsequent terms are $\{\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2,...,\hat{x}_{\frac{N-1}{2}-2},\hat{x}_{\frac{N-1}{2}-1},\hat{x}_{\frac{N-1}{2}}\}$. The inverse DFT is then
$$x_n=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-\frac{N-1}{2}}^{k=\frac{N-1}{2}}\hat{x}_ke^{2\pi i\frac{nk}{N}}$$

If $N$ is even the first $(N-2)/2$ terms are $\{\hat{x}_{-\frac{N-2}{2}},\hat{x}_{-\frac{N-2}{2}+1},\hat{x}_{-\frac{N-1}{2}+2},...,\hat{x}_{-2},\hat{x}_{-1}\}$, then the next term is $\hat{x}_0$ and the subsequent terms are $\{\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2,...,\hat{x}_{\frac{N-2}{2}-2},\hat{x}_{\frac{N-2}{2}-1},\hat{x}_{\frac{N-2}{2}}\}$ and then there is an additional term $\hat{x}_\frac{N}{2}$. The inverse DFT is then
$$x_n=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-\frac{N-2}{2}}^{k=\frac{N}{2}}\hat{x}_ke^{2\pi i\frac{nk}{N}}$$
Remember that, in general, you have to use exactly these ranges to reconstruct the data properly exactly as you had it before using the DFT. This is due to a number of phenomena related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

---

For partial reconstruction using the first $Q$ low frequency terms of the DFT, you have to compute

$$x_n^Q=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-Q}^{Q}\hat{x}_ke^{2\pi i\frac{nk}{N}}$$

Comment: Thank you. This does not solve my problem, but it definitely improved my algorithm.

Comment: You're welcome!